# OOP and forward declaration of structure in C

Tags: c, oop, struct, compilation

I am studying C language and have recently learned how to write the OOP using C. Most part of it was not hard that much to understand for me except the name of structures type used to create new class.

My textbook used `struct dummy_t` for forward declaration and `typedef struct {...} dummy_t` for its definition. In my understanding, these are two different type because the former is `struct dummy` type and the later is `struct` type without a name tag but the sample code from the textbook worked well.

So I deliberately modified the sample code so that the difference in the names of structures will be much clearer. Below are the lines of code I tried.

```
//class.h

struct test_a;
struct test_a * test_init(void);
void test_print(struct test_a*);
```

```
//class.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dummy{
    int x;
    int y;
} test_b;

test_b * test_init(void){
    test_b * temp = (test_b *) malloc(sizeof(test_b));
    temp->x = 10;
    temp->y = 11;
    return temp;
}

void test_print(test_b* obj){
    printf("x: %d, y: %d\n", obj->x, obj->y);
}
```

```
//main.c
#include "class.h"

int main(void){
    struct test_a * obj;
    obj = test_init();
    test_print(obj);

    return 0;
}
// It printed "x: 10, y: 10"
```

As you can see, I used `struct test_a` for forward declaration and `typedef struct dummy {...} test_b` for definition.
I am wondering why I did not get the compile error and it worked.

Comment: You will get the desired compiler error if you `#include<class.h>` in class.c, since the compiler can compare the function signatures and tell you that they conflict.

Comment: The code you have should generate a compiler warning that you are passing the wrong type to `test_print`, so perhaps you need to turn up the compiler diagnostics.

Comment: It's called undefined behavior... which includes the "appear to work" case.

Comment: ***`ow to write the OOP`*** it is not OOP. If you want OOP learn C++

Comment: @0___________ This is a well-known way to achieve private encapsulation in C. How is private encapsulation not OOP? OO is a way to _design_ programs, not a way to write them...

Comment: I'd recommend to do `typedef struct test_a test_a;` in the header and then define the struct simply as `struct test_a { ... };`. The caller shouldn't know or care if the opaque object is a struct or not.

Comment: @Lundin I know what it is for. But I do not know why simply do not write it in C++.  Linux kernel I understand as Linus hates C++ so developers do not have any choice :)

Comment: In general, it goes like this: 1. forward declare in the interface header file (class.h in this case) 2. declare & implement in the implementation module (class.c in this case) 3. include the interface header (class.h) in all modules needing access to your class.

Comment: @0___________ Which is kind of like saying "hey why did you shoot yourself in the foot when you could have blown your whole leg off instead".

Comment: @Lundin Agreed. Simulating OOP in C is definitely like blowing the whole leg off.

Comment: @0___________ I don't believe it is possible to simulate program design. Either you have a program design or you don't, regardless of language.

Comment: @Lundin OK lets call it prothesis (as one has blown its legs off already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why I did not get the compile error

When you compile main.c the compiler is told via a forward declaration from class.h that there is a function with the signature `struct test_a * test_init(void);`

The compiler can't do anything other than just trusting that, i.e. no errors, no warnings can be issued.

When you compile `class.c` there is no forward declaration but only the function definition, i.e. no errors, no warnings.

It's always a good idea to include the .h file into the corresponding .c file. Had you had a `#include "class.h"` in class.c the compiler would have been able to detect the mismatch.

> ..and it worked

What happens is:

1. A pointer to test_b is assigned to a pointer to test_a variable
2. The variable is then passed as argument to a function expecting a pointer to test_b

So once you use the pointer it is used as it was created (i.e. as pointer to test_b). In between you just stored in a variable of another pointer type.

Is that ok? **No**

Storing a pointer to one type in a object defined for another pointer type is not ok. It's undefined behavior. In this case it "just happened to work". In real life it will "just happen to work" on most systems because most systems use the same pointer layout for all types. But according to the C standard it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It 'worked' because you did not include `class.h` in `class.c`. So the compiler can't see the implementation does not match the declaration.

The proper way is (but without the typedef for clarity):

```
// class.h
struct test_a;
struct test_a* test_init(void);

//class.c
#include "class.h"
struct test_a {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct test_a* test_init(void)
{
   ...
}
```

The `struct test_a` in the header file makes the name `test_a` known to the compiler as being a struct. But as it does not now what is in the struct you can only use pointers to such a struct.

The members are defined in the implementation file and can only be used there.

If you want to use a typedef:

```
// header
typedef struct test_a_struct test_a;
test_a* test_init(void);

//implementation
struct test_a_struct {
    int x;
    int y;
};
test_a* test_init(void)
{
    ...
}
```